# Probability problem with samples. Where to start?

Tags: probability

I have this following problem to solve:

"A factory produces rods which are planned to have a length of 80 cm. We assume that the length of the rods variates normaly having the normal distribution.
We pick a sample of 100 rods and measure the length of each. We have the results that the arithmetic mean of the sample is 82 cm and the variance of the sample is 0,025 cm^2. 
Test the hypothesis that the length of the rods produced in the factory have the desired value 80 cm. The alternative hypothesis is that the length differs 80 cm from the desired value."

How should I start solving this problem?

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

obtaining $\mu = 82$, $\mu_{0} = 80$, $n = 100$ and $S^{2} = 0.025$, we can compute the t value:

$$
t = \frac{\mu - \mu_{0}}{\sqrt{\frac{S^2}{n}}} = \frac{82-80}{\sqrt{\frac{0.025}{100}}} \approx 126.49 \ .
$$

From the assumptions, it is also clear that

$$
\frac{\mu - \mu_{0}}{\sqrt{\frac{S^2}{n}}} \sim t(n-1) \ .
$$

Comment: Thank you so much! So is that the answer?